# For a self-adjoint element $a$ in a unital Banach $*$-algebra, is it true that $\|a\| \mathbb{1} -a \geq 0$?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

In a Banach $*$-algebra positive elements can be defined as finite sums of the sort $\sum\limits_k b_k^*b_k$, is it true then that, for a self-adjoint $a$, the expression $\|a\|\mathbb{1} -a$ is a positive element in a Banach $*$-algebra, or is it true just for $C^*$-algebras, where arguments can be made about the spectrum to guarantee positivity of $\|a\|\mathbb{1} -a$ ? That is, is there a easy way to write  $\|a\|\mathbb{1} -a$ as a finite sum of the form $\sum\limits_k b_k^*b_k$?

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, I made a mess in the title.

Comment: I feel like this is unlikely to be true. If there’s someone proficient in Fourier analysis, perhaps they can help check whether the following example works: in the convolution algebra $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ (with the involution given by sending a group element to its inverse), if $e$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $2-e-e^{-1}$ is of the required form, but I don’t think it can be written as $\sum_k b_k^\ast b_k$.

Comment: @DavidGao, so the proof for $C^∗$-algebras, necessarily doesn't go through writing $\|a\| \mathbb{1}-a$ as some sum $\sum_k b^*_k b_k$?

Comment: @FelipeDilho I mean, I’m just suggesting that might be a counterexample, I don’t know how to prove it. But about the proof for $C^\ast$-algebras, it does show that there exists a $b$ such that $\|a\|1 - a = b^\ast b$. In fact, $b$ can be chosen as positive itself. The proof even yields a sequence of polynomials $p_i$ such that $b$ is the limit of $p_i(a)$. However, the fact that the sequence $(p_i(a))_i$ converges at all relies on the fact that the background algebra is a $C^\ast$-algebra, more precisely by using the $C^\ast$-identity, so it does not generalize to Banach $\ast$-algebras.

Comment: @FelipeDilho If you haven’t seen it, I’d suggest reading the proof of Gelfand duality, which yields this fact. You will see how it uses the $C^\ast$ identity in an essential way. Again, I’m not saying I know how to prove the question you asked has a negative answer, but given how the result is proved for $C^\ast$-algebras, I find it hard to believe this could be true for general Banach $\ast$-algebras.

Comment: Also, another perspective to understand why the proof works in $C^\ast$-algebras is because the square root function is continuous, and $C^\ast$-algebras are closed under continuous functional calculus. Banach algebras, on the other hand, are only closed under holomorphic functional calculus, but the square root function is not holomorphic.

Comment: @DavidGao I have proved both the commutative and noncommutative versions of the  Gelfand-Naimark  theorem and have in no way used directly that $\|a\|-a=b^*b$. The idea to use the square root seems to work, since $\|a\|-a$ is self-adjoint, hence I can write the self-adjoint element $(\|a\|-a)^\frac{1}{2}$, hence $\|a\|-a = ((\|a\|-a)^\frac{1}{2})^*(\|a\|-a)^\frac{1}{2}$, and $\|a\|-a$ is positive and where $(\|a\|-a)^\frac{1}{2}(\|a\|-a)^\frac{1}{2}=\|a\|-a$ by the homomorphism property of the continuous functional calculus applied to the square root function.

Comment: On a last request, @DavidGao, would you know how to prove for a $C^*$-algebra, that $\left\|  - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right\| \leq 1$ for a positive element $a \neq 0$? using the norm innequalities just give   $0 \leq \left\|  - \frac{a}{\|a\|}\right\| \leq 2$, is this diminishing of $2$ to $1$ a consequnce of the $C^*$-condition also?

Comment: I was not suggesting that the proof of Gelfand duality requires this fact. I meant that this fact follows from Gelfand duality, precisely through your reasoning, i.e., through using continuous functional calculus. (Recall that continuous functional calculus is a consequence of Gelfand duality.) And the proof of Gelfand duality relies essentially on the $C^\ast$ identity (i.e., $\|a^\ast a\| =\|a\|^2$, which is what distinguishes $C^\ast$-algebras among general Banach $\ast$-algebras). As such, the statement seems unlikely to hold for general Banach $\ast$-algebras.

Comment: For your second question, since $a$ is positive, $\sigma(a) \subset [0, a]$, so $\sigma(1-a/\|a\|) \subset [0, 1]$. As $1-a/\|a\|$ is clearly self-adjoint, its norm equals its spectral radius, which is bounded by 1 since its spectrum is contained in $[0, 1]$.

Comment: The fact that for self-adjoint elements, spectral radius and norm coincide is unique to $C^\ast$-algebras. That is needed in the above proof, so presumably this fact does not hold for general Banach $\ast$-algebras. (Also, I’m not sure in a general Banach $\ast$-algebra, you even have the spectra of positive elements are contained in positive reals.)

Comment: Here is a specific example that shows $\|1-a/\|a\|\|\leq 1$ fails in general Banach $\ast$-algebras. Again, consider the convolution algebra $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ and let $e$ be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $a=(e+e^2+e^3)(e^{-1}+e^{-2}+e^{-3})$ is positive. You can then check by direct calculation that $\|1-a/\|a\|\|=4/3$.